# assigning font size in .sty files

Tags: fonts, packages, fontsize, fontspec, templates

I am using a LaTeX template which contains a `.sty` file.
The problem is that I am getting error for the below line which is shown below it.

```
\font\chaptocfont=\helveticabold
```

ERROR:

```
! Font \tocarttitlefont=9plb8t not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again>
\font
l.93 \font
\chaptocfont=\helveticabold
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
```

How to set font size for this

Please help me fixing this

Latex file can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/76nxbn6cje5qbe4/Latex-v4.rar

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

The `\font` command is a TeX primitive; its syntax is

```
\font\cs=<TFM file name>
```

For instance, Plain TeX says

```
\font\tenrm=cmr10
```

So your `\font\tenrm=\helveticabold` goes wrong; one should know how the nonstandard `\helveticabold` command is defined (note that TeX does macro expansion after the optional equals sign). I guess that

```
\newcommand{\chaptocfont}{\helveticabold}
```

could be what you're looking for. Or

```
\newcommand{\chaptocfont}{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{phv}{b}{n}}
```

that does an explicit choice of Helvetica bold.

However the error is *not* at `\chaptocfont`, but at usage of

```
\tocarttitlefont
```

The error message says it's set to a font that you don't have on your system. According to the conventions on font names it refers to a Palatino font from an unknown foundry.

The class or some package you're using is at fault.

Comment: Thanks egreg for your answer. But I am a tyro in latex. Would u please take a look at the uploaded file and help me with the error? Thank you